# Can a class inherit from another class template concretized by itself?

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++11, template-classes

I was going through some code and I found something like this:

```
class GarbageCollectorProcess : public process::Process<GarbageCollectorProcess>
```

I was wondering if this was a valid thing to do. If yes, shouldn't this lead to some kind of a self definition loop because we are defining a GarbageCollectorProcess using another class that depends on the definition of GarbageCollectorProcess?

Answer (score 5):

> *"I was wondering if this was a valid thing to do."*

Yes this is valid, and also a very common pattern called Curiously Recurring Template Pattern, or short [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern).

It's used to implement static polymorphism for instance.

> *"If yes, shouldn't this lead to some kind of a self definition loop because we are defining a GarbageCollectorProcess using another class that depends on the definition of GarbageCollectorProcess?"*

No, there's no *self definition loop*. The template class is instantiated just once.

Answer (score 1):

It's valid thing to do.
This is how [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) working.